# Program crashing and returning 255

Tags: c, crash

I'm coding a "Rock, Papers and Scissors" program. When the player loses or wins a match, it keeps track of the player's score and saves it to disk. But I don't know why, the program runs, there are no building errors or warnings, but whenever the score changes, the program crashes and returns 255.

```
// Pedra, papel e tesoura

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void showRes(int cho1);

int scorei;
char score[128];

int main()
{
    int ctemp,done;
    char cho1;
    FILE *sco;

    sco = fopen("score.txt","r");
    if(sco == NULL)
        scorei = 0;
    else
    {
        fread(score,128,1,sco);
        scorei = atoi(score);
    }
    fclose(sco);
    sco = fopen("score.txt","w");

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    done = 0;
    printf("Pedra, Papel e Tesoura\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\n Score: %08d\n",scorei);
        printf("\nDigite '1' para 'Pedra', '2' para 'Papel', '3' para 'Tesoura' ou 'Q' para sair: ");
        cho1 = toupper(getchar());
        fflush(stdin);
        ctemp = cho1;
        switch(ctemp)
        {
            case 49:
            case 50:
            case 51:
                showRes(ctemp);
                break;
            case 81:
                done = 1;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Escolha Inv%clida!\n",160);
                break;
        }
        fwrite(scorei,sizeof(int),1,sco);
        printf("\nsalvo com sucesso\n\n");
    }
    while(!done);
    fclose(sco);

    return(0);
}

void showRes(int cho)
{
    int ia;

    ia = rand() % 3 + 1;

    if(cho == 49)
    {
        printf("Voc%c escolheu Pedra!\n",136);
        switch(ia)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Pedra!\n");
                printf("Empate!");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Papel!\n");
                printf("Voc%c perdeu!",136);
                scorei -= 100;
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Tesoura!\n");
                printf("Voc%c venceu!\n",136);
                scorei += 100;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    if(cho == 50)
    {
        printf("Voc%c escolheu Papel!\n",136);
        switch(ia)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Pedra!\n");
                printf("Voc%c venceu!\n",136);
                scorei += 100;
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Papel!\n");
                printf("Empate!\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Tesoura!\n");
                printf("Voc%c perdeu!\n",136);
                scorei -= 100;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    if(cho == 51)
    {
        printf("Voc%c escolheu Tesoura!\n",136);
        switch(ia)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("O Computador escolheu pedra!\n");
                printf("Voc%c perdeu!\n",136);
                scorei -= 100;
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Papel!\n");
                printf("Voc%c venceu!\n",136);
                scorei += 100;
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("O Computador escolheu Tesoura!\n");
                printf("Empate!\n");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this line doesn't make sense : fwrite(scorei,sizeof(int),1,sco); shouldn't you write to a file?? you are writing to an integer.

Comment: Please learn to debug enough to identify the failure line. You cannot expect to make progress unless you learn to debug.

Comment: Isn't that how we write info to a file? `sco = fopen("score.txt","w");`, so that `fwrite(scorei,sizeof(int),1,sco);` is writing the variable "scorei" into "score.txt", isn't it? @zero.zero.seven

Comment: No, you needs &scorei, the address of the data you want to write. Are you ignoring warnings from the compiler? They are trying to tell you these things.

Comment: you should pick-up a book or read an online tutorial. search google for "fwrite + C"

Comment: size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

Comment: oh hell, it's the opposite of write :) apologies.

Comment: @Charlie-Burns Thanks, that fixed for me. I get messed up with the fwrite function because I've written somethings that didn't require the ampersand and some that did, that's where I got confused. Thank you all.

Comment: I was referring to this func in my mind:
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);

Comment: @GabrielTaets, your welcome. You might find readings the warnings from the compiler is faster and easier than asking on StackOveflow.

Comment: Never use this: `fflush(stdin);`, you cannot flush input stream, its an Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @CharlieBurns idk why but the compiler didn't complain about that. As I said on the question, I wasn't getting any errors or warnings, so I assumed there was nothing wrong with the functions although the program was still crashing. I'm not used to codeblocks but I have to use it since I'm not on my own computer, perhaps that's why I'm such a mess right now. @0xF1 why is that so? All of the books I've read so far uses `fflush(stdin)`, and none of the program I've written  complained about using it.s

Comment: See #3 here http://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/ten-codeblocks-tips/

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the cause of the crash, but you're reading the file as if it contained text, but writing binary values to it.  Further, successive values are being added to the file, but you only read 1 out.